# Why does the `count` function work but not `sum`?

Tags: mysql, select, sum

The idea is to sum across several tables. I can get `COUNT` to work, but when I change it to `SUM` I get an error.

> Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) from (select * from t1 union select * from t2 union select * from t3 ) a' at line 1

```
create table t1(s int);
create table t2(s int);
create table t3(s int);

insert into t1 values(1);
insert into t2 values(2);
insert into t3 values(3);

select count(*) from 
(select * from t1 union 
 select * from t2 union 
 select * from t3
) as ta;
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ocK8CNZW2uTXQBTE8PRXNP/1)

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Comment: @Martin; I can't see where it says `sum` needs a column name.

Comment: `COUNT` counts rows whereas `SUM` calculates summary from one column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COUNT` has a special treatment for `*` that counts the rows regardless of any `null` values. `SUM` must take a (numeric) expression as its argument.

In this example, you could use `sum(s)`:

```sql
select sum(s) from 
(select * from t1 union 
 select * from t2 union 
 select * from t3
) as ta;
```

**[FBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eXtrBG6RV123uXmWgtUWBS/0)**

Comment: I'd go further and use `select s`, not `select *` in the individual selects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, selecting * is deeply inefficient on larger datasets. And it's lazy.

Comment: I wanted to apply as little changes as possible to the OP's query to highlight the usage of `sum`. In a "real" scenario, I agree, `s` should be selected directly.

Comment: Slight correction, for what it's worth: `SUM()` must have an expression as an argument. The expression may be a single column, but it may be a more complex expression. But it's correct that `COUNT(*)` is the only aggregate function that takes `*`.

Comment: One should use `UNION ALL` (basic `UNION` will do `DISTINCT`)

Comment: @BillKarwin good point - using "column" was a poor choice on my behalf. Edited and fixed.